# Creating view to display fields from numerous select statements

Tags: sql, view

I have a bunch of seperate little select queries that I need to put in a view or two views that could be eventually joined and need suggestions. I am using a third party ad hoc application that does not play nice with stored procedures so temp table would not be suitable. Does anybody have any suggestions on how this could be accomplished? Below are the queries:

```
select count(cmrckid)as TotalRDIs
FROM  tblCMRCK 


select count(AccountID)as TotalMerchants
FROM  tblAccounts


select count(AccountID)as TotalActiveMerchants
FROM  tblAccounts
where inactive = 0


select count(AccountID)as TotalInActiveMerchants
FROM  tblAccounts
where inactive = 1


select count(AccountID)as TotalwithRDIs
FROM  [tblAccounts] a WITH (NOLOCK) inner join
      [tblcmrck] c WITH (NOLOCK) on a.configid=c.configid and a.accountid=c.acctid


select COUNT(AccountID) as ActivewithRDIs
FROM  [tblAccounts] a WITH (NOLOCK) inner join
      [tblcmrck] c WITH (NOLOCK) on a.configid=c.configid and a.accountid=c.acctid 
      where a.Inactive = 0


select COUNT(AccountID) as ActivewithoutRDIs
FROM  [tblAccounts] a WITH (NOLOCK) 
      where a.inactive = 0 and a.AccountID not in (select AcctID from tblCMRCK)



--select 'Total Active Merchants' / 'Total Merchants' as 'PctActive'
--from #tmptable


--select 'Total InActive Merchants' / 'Total Merchants' as 'PctInActive'
--from #tmpTableExample2


--select 'Active with RDIs' / 'Total Merchants' as 'PctActivewithRDIs'
--FROM  #tmpTableExample


--select 'Active without RDIs' / 'Total Merchants' as 'PctActivewithoutRDIs'
--FROM  #tmpTableExample
```

Comment: are you sure you don't want select count(distinct field)

Comment: the column auto increments so I dont have to worry about them being distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something more like this:

```
SELECT 
    TotalMerchants, 
    TotalRDIs,
    inactive, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT AccountID) AS totalAccounts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT AccountID) / TotalMerchants AS pct,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS isInRDI,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  / TotalMerchants AS pctRDI
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT AccountID) AS TotalMerchants
    FROM  
        tblAccounts) tm,
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT AcctID) AS  TotalRDIs 
    FROM 
        tblCMRCK) tr,
    tblAccounts  a LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblCMRCK c ON
    a.configid=c.configid AND 
    a.accountid=c.acctid
GROUP BY
    TotalMerchants, 
    TotalRDIs,
    inactive
```

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be combined:

```
select count(AccountID)as TotalActiveMerchants
FROM  tblAccounts
where inactive = 0

select count(AccountID)as TotalInActiveMerchants
FROM  tblAccounts
where inactive = 1
```

Into:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN inactive = 0 THEN TotalActiveMerchants
          ELSE TotalInactiveMerchants
        end              AS metric,
        Count(accountid) AS value
FROM   tblaccounts
WHERE  inactive IN ( 0, 1 )
GROUP  BY inactive
```

Then you can simply stack your metrics into a single statement:

```
SELECT 'TotalRDIs' AS metric,
       Count(cmrckid) AS value
FROM   tblcmrck
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TotalMerchants' AS metric,
       Count(accountid)
FROM   tblaccounts
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE
          WHEN inactive = 0 THEN TotalActiveMerchants
          ELSE TotalInactiveMerchants
        end              AS metric,
        Count(accountid) AS value
FROM   tblaccounts
WHERE  inactive IN ( 0, 1 )
GROUP  BY inactive
...
```

Which would look something like:

```
metric                  value
TotalRDIs               0
TotalMerchants          0
TotalActiveMerchants    0
TotalInactiveMerchants  0
...
```

Comment: @gogo You can certainly add empty columns to make it match.